# Solution for Unicode character escape sequence for password fields

Tags: java, html

When I update my password field with any Unicode characters (like \u), it throws this error:

```
"SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence".
```

Could anyone suggest a solution without doing replacement since this is a password field?

Comment: Is your HTML using unicode?

Comment: Unclear. How do you read your input?

Comment: Please provide more detail about how the input is read and what is generating the error.